# WooCommerce: Check if cart item is free and add class to table row

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I want to add an extra class to the cart table row if the product is free (price of 0).

I do have a way to add an extra class:

```
function custom_add_cart_item_classes( $class, $values, $values_key ) {

    if ( isset( $values[ 'product_id' ] ) ) {
        $class .= ' cart_item_' . $values[ 'product_id' ];
        
        // This is the problem: $cart_item is not available here
        $get_item_cart_price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();
        if ($get_item_cart_price == '0') :
            $class .= ' cart_item_free';
        endif;
        
    }

    return $class;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'custom_add_cart_item_classes', 10, 3 );
```

The problem is, that I cannot access `$cart_item` in the function.
I made a `var_dump` for `$values` and found the product ID in it.

Is there any way to get the `$cart_item` with the product ID? Or any other way to load that element here?

EDIT: I need the cart item because the price is changed in the cart. The regular product price is not free.

Comment: Why do you need the cart item, when you have the product ID? The product is what is “free” here, is it not? `wc_get_product` gets you the product based on ID.

Comment: Sorry, I need the cart item because the price is changed in the cart. The regular product price is not free.

Comment: According to docs, the second parameter passed in to the callback function _is_ the cart item object. You just named your function parameter $value, so that is what you need to use to access it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tested OK with WC 4.9.0**

```
function custom_add_cart_item_classes( $class, $values, $values_key ) {

    
        if ( isset( $values[ 'data' ] ) ) {
            $product = $values[ 'data' ];
            if(!$product->get_price()){
                $class .= ' cart_item_free';
            }
        }

    return $class;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'custom_add_cart_item_classes', 10, 3 );
```